# postgres function returns unexpected set

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a simple function that returns a geometry for a given ZIP code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public._zip_geom(IN zip VARCHAR)
RETURNS SETOF geometry AS $$
    SELECT "the_geom_4326" FROM "shapes"."zip_polys" a WHERE a."zip" = zip
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

that I call with `SELECT public._zip_geom('80302');`.

When the return is defined as `SETOF geometry`, I get *all* geometries in the `zip_polys` table. When I change it to just `geometry`, I get a single geometry, but not the geometry that matches the provided ZIP code.

Why is that and how do I write a function that will return the correct value?

Comment: Rename the function argument to something that  is not `zip`, eg `CREATE FUNCTION public._zip_geom(IN _zip VARCHAR)` ... `SELECT "the_geom_4326" FROM "shapes"."zip_polys" a WHERE a."zip" = _zip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function argument collides with a column name (Duh!), you could try:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public._zip_geom(IN _omg VARCHAR)
RETURNS SETOF geometry AS $$
    SELECT "the_geom_4326" FROM "shapes"."zip_polys" a WHERE a."zip" = _omg
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

The prefix underscore in `_doh` or `_zip` is more or less a convention for arguments; column names *cannot* start with an underscore, so `_omg` is collision free.